# Get Excel not to equally space values along the y-axis

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007

I am graphing the height above sea level obtained by GPS at 12 measuring stations, which are distributed along a straight line but NOT equidistantly.

Excel does a nice job of creating a suitable Y axis. But, it insists on placing the 12 stations equidistantly along the X axis.

Consequently, the line graph does not represent the true cross section of the terrain. It is only true at the stations themselves.

Surely there must be a way that I can enter the actual distances between the stations into a column, and get Excel to read from that column and space the values accordingly? It is such a basic mapping procedure for geologists and many others.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You could try using a scatter / XY chart type.

Alternatively, you could tell Excel that the X values are dates(!): Excel then inserts the "missing" days and, for a column type chart leaves the column blank.