# Excel x-axis scale

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Excel axis problem](https://superuser.com/questions/134504/excel-axis-problem)

I jumped from an older version of Excel to the new ribbon interface and am stumped trying to make a simple graph.

I have a set of pair values that go something like this:

```
X    Y
1    .5
2    .4
3    .35
4    .33
5    .3
10   .2
15   .15
20   .1
```

When I plot a line graph I get the x-axis as if the X's are text and each one is a category. I would like to get the graph where the 10, 15 and 20 values are put in their proportional place, with gaps between them wider than between the first elements. I'm sure Excel must be able to do this but I can't find how in the new interface.

Comment: Try a scatter chart with smooth lines, is that what you are after?

Comment: "Gaps between them wider than the first elements": like a logarithmic scale? What would you have done in the previous version of Excel to achieve this? (Also are you now on Excel 2010 or 2007?)

Comment: Tog, add that as an answer and I'll mark it approved. I ended up figuring it out on my own but it's exactly what you wrote.

Comment: Use Tog's approach, XY Scatter Chart, but use markers with straight lines; do not use smoothed lines. Smoothed lines indicate data where none exists.

Comment: @pnuts - Yes and no. The markers should be enough. People will see the curved lines and give them more emphasis than deserved. Also in some cases, the smoothed lines will stray far beyond where data is even possible.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a scatter chart with smooth lines